# OPENCART :Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.0.0.0 and trying to upload a module/extension in it through extension installer.But it shows an error "Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found!"

Comment: Don't use OpenCart 2.0.0.0 version. many bug available in this version. I recommended use latest OpenCart version 2.2.0.0.

Comment: @Mithu, Please show us directory structure of your module.