# Create OCMOD xml

Tags: opencart

Hi I have created a OC Module and followed [this](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) to create ocmod.xml. But did not succeed it is showing "Directory containing files to be uploaded could not be found!"

Here are my directory structure filename is moduletimes_2.0.x_Install.ocmod.zip

```
/upload/admin/controller ...
/upload/admin/language ...
/upload/admin/model ...
/upload/admin/view ...
/install.xml
```

My xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Modification Default</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>OpenCart Ltd</author>
    <link>http://www.opencart.com</link>    
</modification>
```

I have also found another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183914/opencart-directory-containing-files-to-be-uploaded-could-not-be-found). Please help me to create installable module.

Answer (score 0):

Looks allright, do you have a system/upload directory?

Answer (score 0):

you must go to extension - upload extension, when you download your file, and you will see your module. 
but have some changes opencart 2.1 and 2.3 to look list of modules.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include install.xml file if you don't have to change anything.
You can only install moduletimes_2.0.x_Install.ocmod.zip file without install.xml file.
And also SET FTP details in your admin settings page.
Thanks,
Prasant